# How to speed up this vb code in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code in an Excel sheet for calculation. Unfortunately it is taking too much time to calculate and the page keeps flickering.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Activate() 
    BeginRow = 1  
    EndRow = 300
    ChkCol = 3

     For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
     If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = "B" Then
     Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
     Else
     Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
     End If
     Next RowCnt     
     End Sub
```

It is for an attendance management software and there are 4 sheets. I am using this code for all sheets except in `Sheet1`. Master data is entered in `sheet1`.
Please help me to speed up this process.

Comment: add at the beginning  `Application.ScreenUpdating = false` and ` `Application.ScreenUpdating = true` at the end.

Comment: Why not use `Autofilter`? This can be resolved in less than a second, even.

Comment: Although it does not affect the time so much here, not that you are declaring your variables as variants, not longs as you should be.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @BK201 that you can also use autofilter. Here is another faster method. I say faster because it doesn't show/hide the rows in a loop. Additionally you can sandwhich your code between `Application.ScreenUpdating = false` and `Application.ScreenUpdating = true` to stop the flickering as @KazJaw suggested.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim BeginRow As Long, EndRow As Long
    Dim ChkCol As Long, RowCnt As Long
    Dim rngHide As Range

    BeginRow = 1: EndRow = 300: ChkCol = 3

    '~~> Unhide all the rows
    Rows("1:300").EntireRow.Hidden = False

    '~~> Loop through the rows and identify which rows needs to be hidden
    For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
        If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = "B" Then
            If rngHide Is Nothing Then
                Set rngHide = Rows(RowCnt)
            Else
                Set rngHide = Union(rngHide, Rows(RowCnt))
            End If
        End If
    Next RowCnt

    '~~> Hide the rows  in one go
    If Not rngHide Is Nothing Then rngHide.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This method is unnecessarily expensive. Why unhide all rows if you are going to loop over them anyway?

Comment: @Issun: unhiding rows in one go in Excel is not `expensive` at all :) Also unhiding the rows in the beginning will simply put less stress on your For-next Loop.

Comment: friend, 

first of all let me tell you that I am very fresher to the VB side. So consider my knowledge according to that level.

I was using the quoted code in Sheet2, sheet3 and in sheet 4 too...

Comment: @Anesh: `first of all let me tell you that I am very fresher to the VB side.` Then this is a perfect opportunity to understand what the code does and learn at the same time ;)

Comment: Friend,

First of all let me tell you that I am very fresher in the VB sector.
So consider my knowledge according to that only.

Also I was using the quoted code in Sheet2, sheet3 and in Sheet4 too. That might be the cause to slower the process, can you please guide me how to make it in a single code which should work when I  make any changes in Sheet 1. Also please advice me where to copy this code

Comment: @Anesh: You need to paste the code that I gave in the sheet code area of Sheet2, sheet3 and in Sheet4

Comment: Hi Sidharth,

I DID THAT. Thanks its working. You are Brilliant dude. :-)
But there is only a small flickering while activating the worksheet. is there any problem with that? 

Also sidharth, do you have any fast and simple vb or excel software to manage the attendace of employees? Can I send my project you? can you make it much better format? kindly advice me how to send  that to you, if possible...Thanks in adavance dear

Comment: @Anesh: Did you sandwhich your code between `Application.ScreenUpdating = false` and `Application.ScreenUpdating = true` to stop the flickering as @KazJaw suggested? Regarding your  project, if you want to hire my professional services then see the link in my profile.

Comment: Thanks Sidharth, it is perfect now after applying @KazJaw's idea. I will contact you formally as soon as possible.

Comment: One more doubt Sidharth. How and where I can upload my Xlsm file and do the updation. I mean, I want my HR people to do the updation on regular basis on this XlSM file from branch office and I my self want to see the same at my Head office. Is there any way for that. I think Google docs cannot be possible.

Comment: This should go as a separate question  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I just quickly looked at your problem. It seems hiding an entire row takes a lot of time. So you need to check that a row is not hidden already before you hide it. Or already showing if you want to unhide it. I think this code will fix the problem

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
BeginRow = 1
EndRow = 300
ChkCol = 3

 For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
 If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = "B" Then
    If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
    Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
 Else
    If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
    Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
 End If
 Next RowCnt
 End Sub
```

Your code also ran slowly on my computer but this code worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Constantly calling up Excel is expensive. Dumping the data you need to check into a variant array and working on that is much faster. Also as mentioned, you need to turn off screenupdating, otherwise calculations will be occuring left and right, speeding things down considerbaly.

Here's how to use a variant array in the context you are using (hide rows with "B" in column C, unhide if not "B"):

```
Sub improvedSpeed()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim varray() As Variant
Dim i As Long

varray() = Range("C1:C300").Value

For i = 1 To 300
    If varray(i, 1) = "B" Then
        Rows(i).Hidden = True
    Else
        Rows(i).Hidden = False
    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```